# Extracting 2 separate records based on one value and copy to 2 separate files using java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have one log file which looks like this:

```
TxID=JM-70106-7001-20150803150010-588177-ITP-5793501-JM013MJBT458T
TxIN =JM7001                            20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000
InitTX=1
LogTX=1
ProcessTX=0
DeliverTX=0
LogTX=0
DeliverTXstats=0
TXstat=Request  TX Complete
TxOUT=JM7001                            20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000
 }]
TxID=JM-70106-7001-20150803150010-588177-ITP-5793501-JM013MJBT458T
TxIN =JM7002                           20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000
InitTX=0
LogTX=0
ProcessTX=0
DeliverTX=1
LogTX=2
DeliverTXstats=0
TXstat=Response TX Complete
TxOUT=JM7002                           20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000
 }]
```

I need to extract successful request and response raw messages from the log file using a Java program based on below conditions:
1.      Scan for line that have “TxID=…”

2. See if the next 8th line has “TXstat=Request  TX Complete”. If so, get its immediate next line, which is a successful raw request message.
3. Scan for lines that have the same TxID=… from step 1, and check for line that has  “TXstat=Response TX Complete”.
4. Get the next line which is a successful response that corresponds to the request found in step 2.

Repeat step 1~4 to find all successful request and response messages and put them in the separate Request and the Response output files.

I have written a code but not sure how to meet all conditions.

[Java Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LLYt.png)

Main part of Code:

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

```
    prop=GetReqResRawMsg.readPropertiesFile();
    String line;
    String brokerInputFileName=prop.getProperty("brokerInputFileName");
    String brokerRequestFileName=prop.getProperty("brokerRequestFileName");
    //String brokerReponseFileName=prop.getProperty("brokerResponseFileName");
try(BufferedReader reqReader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(brokerInputFileName)));
    BufferedReader reqReader2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(brokerInputFileName)));
        FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(brokerRequestFileName);
        ){

    while((line=reqReader1.readLine())!=null){
        //System.out.println(line);
        Scanner request=new Scanner(line).useDelimiter("TxID");
        while(request.hasNextLine()){
            String txOut=request.nextLine();
            String reqOut;
            if(txOut.indexOf("TXstat=Request  TX Complete")!=-1)
        {
            reqOut=reqReader1.readLine();
            if(reqOut.indexOf("TxOUT")!=-1){

                String[] splitreqOut=reqOut.split("=");
                String reqRawMess=splitreqOut[1];

                fileWriter.write(reqRawMess);
                fileWriter.append("\n");

            }   
        }   

        }

    }
}
}
```

Appreciate any help!!

Regards
Karthik

Comment: Add the code as Text not as image

Comment: Run it and see whether it works.

Comment: you need to paste code here , the screen shot you posted , is not complete and please read this before making any edit(http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Jens I have added the code

Comment: now add the log file too[

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I have added log file too.

Comment: I am not getting your second point

Comment: @AsteriskNinja, If you see the logs , first we need to make a note of 'TxID' value ,next
 is to check if its request or response which we can get from the 'TXstat' (8th line from TxID). If its request then copy the next line value i.e. 'TxOUT' to request file and 
for the same TxID response TxOut value to response file. Hope this is clear.

Comment: correct me If i am wrong , you want to select only next line ie, like in your 8th line you want  `TxOUT=JM7001                            20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000` in console, ?

Comment: @AsteriskNinja I want to copy only the value of TxOUT to a file, i.e. if its request then to request file and corresponding response of the request to response file.

Comment: you need to be sure about the value you want , why dont you paste the sample output so , there will be better understandign

Comment: @AsteriskNinja From the above file I want to paste the request TxOUT value i.e. JM7001                            20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000 to request file and the same response TxOUT value i.e. JM7001                            20150803150010588177ITP57935015793570185JM013MJBT458T           RCOLE012  EITP7010600000 to response file. I hope this is very clear.